# java barcode reader

Tags: java, barcode

anyone have any idea about how to create java program that can read barcode

Comment: Do you get the input as a picture? Because usually scanners already decode the barcode, so there is no difference between scanning and using the keyboard.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing) provides Java source code that reads most any common format (UPC, EAN, QR codes, etc.). It provides source to a complete Android and J2ME app, and source for a basic Java-based app.

Comment: It's worth noting that ZXing is native code with a Java-based API, not pure Java, and therefore could cause deployment headaches if you're working with multiple architectures.

Comment: This is not at all true - it is pure Java and always has been. Maybe you are thinking of ports but they are entirely separate.

Comment: Looking again, you're clearly right.  I was getting confused by the box at the bottom of the web site that describes the project as having a "main language" of C++; the rest of the text clearly shows that it is this box that is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand how barcode readers work, then you need to sort all the information you have gathered and create neat UML diagrams so that you could organize everything you'll need.

But I think this will need more than Java to work, it needs some computer engineering skills as well.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the open source Java libraries to generate barcodes such as [Barbecue](http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/) and Barcode4J

http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net supports most formats like Code 39, UPC-A, UPC-E, EAN-13 etc

Comment: The OP asked about reading barcodes, not generating them.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at JavaBar Barcode Decoding/Rendering Library.  It's written in 100% Java, and released under a BSD license.

Comment: Just for completeness, the URL: http://roncemer.com/software-development/java-bar-code-decoder-and-generator/